Is there any way in Russian to say "going fine"?
For example, "my studies are going fine", or "my holidays are going well"?

"Учёба нормально", "каникулы хорошо" - usually in reply to "Как учёба?", "Как каникулы?"

Use "хорошо" or "нормально" - "Занятия хорошо, выходные нормально!".

An exact but very conversational analogue, never to be used in written texts, is: "всё путём".
(Some will say that this is a lower-class argot. Which it probably is.)
PS.
In everyday life, also much stronger synonyms are employed,
but I am not sure if you want to know them.

In addition to existing answer, if you're not comfortable without verb then the relevant one is often провожу/провёл or идёт/прошёл.
Каникулы провожу хорошо, учёба прошла нормально.

Most people just use нормально in most cases. Another common alternative would be в порядке, but it does not works in every context. Good examples:
— Учёба в порядке / с учёбой всё в порядке
— Здоровье в порядке
— Дела в порядке
— Работа в порядке

But it sounds a little strange when used with holidays. Literally it means “in order”, so it is probably more appropriate in contexts where the order is possible... (not quite sure)

In case you need an adequate, not a verbatim translation:
Russians, actually, not often say учёба идёт хорошо / учёба нормально. More common phrases are:
- Как в школе дела? / Как учёба?
- В школе (в университете, в институте, в колледже, в лицее) у меня всё хорошо (нормально).

- Как каникулы? / Как выходные?
- Да нормально. / Очень даже неплохо. / Не жалуюсь. / Грех жаловаться. / Не очень. / Плохо. / Ужасно.

Праздники прошли нормально sounds good too, but only for the past tense.
Hope that helps!

Perhaps, in modern spoken Russian there is no way to properly express "going fine".
The literal translation means идут ладно which is correct by itself. You can say мои занятия идут ладно (my studies are going fine). However, it doesn't sound natural, because in modern spoken Russian you have to skip pronoun and the verb both to make the phrase short. You can think of it as "studies are fine", where the verb and pronoun are implied.
Additionally, using the word "fine" as a synonym to "well" is outdate. Normally, you should always use "going well" instead of "going fine": the phrase my studies are going well (мои занятия идут хорошо) sounds more natural in modern Russian than the former one.
